# Aggregate in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame as follows :

```
Team_1 Team_2 Winning_Team
  A      B         A
  C      A         C
  .      .         .
  .      .         .
```

I want count of matches won and matches played by each team. Output should be in named list format so that I am able to access the counts by name of the team.

Expected Output :

```
Team     Matches_Won   Matches_Played
 A            1            2
 B            0            1
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted based on the `.` showed.

Comment: `.` just shows continuation of data.frame. Nothing else .

Comment: I understand that part.  It would be better if you show the expected output based on the example

Comment: Agreed. I have edited the post

Comment: Try `library(data.table); melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "Winning_Team")[, .(Matches_Won = sum(Winning_Team==value), Matches_Played = .N), .(Team = value)]`

Comment: If you're variables are in factors with all the team names as levels, then you can just do `table(unlist(df[, 1:2]))` to know the matchs played and `table(unlist(df[, 3]))` to know the matchs won